# install anaconda in linux fails

Tags: linux, anaconda

I tried to install Anaconda on a remote linux machine, but during installation the exits with failure. What should I do to solve this?

```
tar: include/qt/QtQuick/5.6.2/QtQuick/private/qquickevents_p_p.h: Cannot open: 
No such file or directory
tar: include/qt/QtQuick/5.6.2/QtQuick/private/qquickrectangle_p_p.h: Cannot 
open: No such file or directory
tar: include/qt/QtQuick/5.6.2/QtQuick/private/qquicktextdocument_p.h: Cannot 
open: No such file or directory
...
...
tar: doc/global/externalsites/external-resources.qdoc: Cannot open: No such 
file or directory
tar: doc/global/externalsites/qt-webpages.qdoc: Cannot open: No such file or 
directory
tar: doc/global/externalsites/qtcreator.qdoc: Cannot open: No such file or 
directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install-linux.html 
I followed this official guide and it fails at step 6 during installation. 
The version I installed is `Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh`

Comment: How are you installing it ?

Comment: @iamauser I've updated my question and add it at the end.

Comment: Your question is probably more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).